# Constraint to check if time greater than 9 am

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

How to check time entry only so that any entry before  is not acceptable?

```
CREATE TABLE demo.event(

ecode       CHAR(4) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
edesc       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
elocation   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
edate       DATE NOT NULL 
            CONSTRAINT date_check CHECK(edate BETWEEN '2016/04/01' AND '2016/04/30'),
etime       TIME NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT time_check CHECK(etime (HOUR > '08:00:00')),
emax        SMALLINT NOT NULL 
            CONSTRAINT emax_check CHECK(emax >=1 OR emax<=1000)
);
```

The above code gave me an error

> ERROR:  column "hour" does not exist

Comment: Show us the **complete** `create table` statement (*edit* your question, do not post code in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a time literal, you need to use the keyword `time` not hour:

```
CONSTRAINT time_check CHECK(etime > TIME '08:00:00'),
```

> *so any entry before 9:00 am not acceptable.*

contradicts the `08:00:00'` you have used, `> TIME '08:00:00'` will allow `08:00:01` (one second after 8am). If you really only want to allowed values after 9am, then use:

```
CONSTRAINT time_check CHECK(etime > TIME '09:00:00'),
```

---

You should also use proper ISO formatted dates to avoid any ambiguity:

```
CONSTRAINT date_check CHECK(edate BETWEEN DATE '2016-04-01' AND DATE '2016-04-30')
```

More details on the proper syntax for date and time literals can be found in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT